# Pivot date of a given month and a column in a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Version. I have the following tables:

Member Table

---

```
Id  Name   IsDeleted  IsDeletedDate
1   James     0         null
2   Joe       1         20-12-2017
3   Carl      0         null
```

Attendance Table

---

```
Id   Date         Status
 1   20-12-2017   {"id":17,"Status":"EveningPermission"},{"id":2,"Status":"Available"},{"id":3,"Status":"Available"},{"id":18,"Status":"Available"},{"id":5,"Status":"Available"},{"id":6,"Status":"Available"},{"id":7,"Status":"Available"},{"id":10,"Status":"Available"},{"id":19,"Status":"Available"},{"id":16,"Status":"Available"},{"id":12,"Status":"Available"},{"id":9,"Status":"Available"},{"id":13,"Status":"Available"},{"id":11,"Status":"Available"},{"id":27,"Status":"Available"},{"id":14,"Status":"Available"},{"id":24,"Status":"Available"},{"id":15,"Status":"Available"},{"id":21,"Status":"Available"},{"id":22,"Status":"Available"},{"id":23,"Status":"Available"},{"id":20,"Status":"Available"},{"id":26,"Status":"Available"},{"id":25,"Status":"Available"}
 2   21-12-2017   {"id":17,"Status":"Available"},{"id":2,"Status":"Available"},{"id":3,"Status":"Available"},{"id":18,"Status":"Available"},{"id":5,"Status":"Available"},{"id":6,"Status":"Available"},{"id":7,"Status":"Available"},{"id":10,"Status":"Available"},{"id":19,"Status":"MorningPermission"},{"id":16,"Status":"Available"},{"id":12,"Status":"Available"},{"id":9,"Status":"Available"},{"id":13,"Status":"Available"},{"id":11,"Status":"Available"},{"id":27,"Status":"Available"},{"id":14,"Status":"Available"},{"id":24,"Status":"Available"},{"id":15,"Status":"Available"},{"id":21,"Status":"Available"},{"id":22,"Status":"Available"},{"id":23,"Status":"Available"},{"id":20,"Status":"Available"},{"id":26,"Status":"Available"},{"id":25,"Status":"Available"}
```

So there are 5 statuses for Attendance which are Available, SickLeave, CasualLeave, MorningPermission, EveningPermission.

My requirement is that I have to pass date like '12 2017'. So I have to generate all the dates in the month of December and my output should be like

```
S.No  Name   1/12  2/12  3/12 ........31/12  Total
1     James   1    0.5    0   ......... 1    (sum from 1/12 to 31/12) 
2     Joe     0.5   1     1   ......... 0    (sum from 1/12 to 31/12)
```

If the Person is Available I will mark as 1, if sick or casual leave I will mark as 0, if morning or Evening permission I will mark as 0.5.

Id field from Member table should be matched with id field in Status field in Attendance(which is a json string).

Comment: Have you stored the statuses as a json-string in your databasetable?

Comment: No the datatype of status in attendance table is nvarchar(max)

Comment: why would you store the attendance table status like that. This is just awful... normalizing the data would save you years off your life

Comment: @scsimon The reason is that, suppose I have 30 members then I had to store 30 different rows for a single date like 12/1/2017   1  available, 12/1/2017  2  sick leave etc.. so to avoid more memory usage I am storing the data's in json format.

Comment: Anyone has solution for this?

Comment: The overhead of normalizing your data is nothing compared to parsing it every time you need it. This is simple with normalized data. If you sitll want to keep the json I suggest you start off with a CTE parsing the json into a normalized result before trying to pivot.